# Validate if a string contains only some characters in javascript

Tags: javascript

I know this question has been asked here many times, but mine is a tad different. I do not want to validate if the string is alphanumeric, I just need it to only consist of a few characters, let's say letters: A, B, a, b and this symbol >.
Is it possible with regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple example:

```
var isValidString = stringToValidate.match(/^[AaBb>]*$/) !== null;
```

Explanation:

[String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) can be called on any string and it will return an array, if the regex matched (containing the matched substrings) or null.

Wrapping the regular expression between caret (`^`) and dollar (`$`) signs will ensure, that you check the string in full length.

You can add any characters between square brackets as you like, it will only match those.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could do something like this.

```
/(?![ABC])./g
```

This will match anything that ISNT A, B or C. Meaning that if it gets a match, your validation should fail.